# Recognize an android drive when I connected it to PC

Tags: java, android, mtp

I want to copy paste an xml file into a directory in my android sdcard (It will be imported later by an android application).

I want to know if there is an easier solution that recognize an android drive like C: D:.

When I connect my android device, it's recognized as "Nexus 7" and inside we find "Mémoire de stockage interne" where we find sdcard folders.

I want to ask if there is an API or a solution that recognize android MTP mode and return only android drives.

Thank you